# How to avoid table crash?

Tags: mysql, corruption

Couple of days back I had a table with 7GB of data and it was showing 63MB of overhead in phpMyAdmin and I mistakenly started its optimization and after working of more than 40 mins it corrupted the whole table.

What are the safe practices to avoid table crash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say to try to use a different storage engine like InnoDB.

It sounds like you were using MyISAM which isn't crash safe. If you want to continue using MyISAM and it crashes in the future, you can fix it with an external program called myisamchk.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk.html

```
 myisamchk --force --key_buffer_size=512M --sort_buffer_size=64M --read_buffer_size=8M --write_buffer_size=8M  /path/to/datadir/*/*.MYI
```

Comment: Any idea how long it will take to repair 7GB table?

Comment: It really depends on your system, but myisamchk has parameters, like increasing memory it can use which can make it faster.

Comment: thx, wanted to give rep but I lack points. :)